# jstl c:set is not working on js code in jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jstl-functions

I have a JSON from a service. I am appending a html block by JSON value and I have to check some values for appropriate display.
I am trying to set discountValue variable but it not working with js variable. How can I solve it?

```
  if (data!="")
                {
                    $.each(data,function(index,element){
                        var intDiscount=parseInt(10);
                        console.log("intDiscount::"+intDiscount);

                        var strIndex='';
                        strIndex+='<div class="card">';
                        strIndex+='<c:set var="discountValue" value="'+intDiscount+'"/>';
                        console.log("${discountValue}");
...
...
...
...
                 }
                 $('#visilabs-FavouriteCategoryTopSeller').append(strIndex);
```

Console log:

```
intDiscount::10
0
```

Comment: JSTL executes at server-side. JavaScript executes at client-side, long after the JSTL has ended generated the HTML + JS code. This makes no sense.

Comment: To add to JB Nizet's comment, this line: `strIndex+='<c:set var="discountValue" value="'+intDiscount+'"/>'` will always be the same as `strIndex+='';` even outsize of an ajax JS call because c:set doesn't print out anything.

Comment: If you have already a JSON- result, there is no need for JSTL. If the JSON result is in `data`, you have to extract your value from data. With your `$.each(data, function(index,element)` you assume, data is an array. If so, you will be called for every arrayelement and have to use the `element ` arg of your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with using if condition with js:

```
if(element.discount>0){
                            strIndex+=                      '           <span class="label label-danger discount">'+'%&nbsp;'+intDiscount+'</span>';
                        }
```

Thanks everyone